# Multiple citations as range: how to?

Tags: bibliographies

I have a number of references and I'd like to cite them in a multiple selection. As they are 12, I'd like them to appear as [12-24] and not [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 and so on].

```
\cite{firstone, secondone, thirdone}
```

I read that the `\cite` module can't manage this but I don't want to use the BibLateX ambient.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [`cite` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/cite).

Comment: May I suggest you substitute the word _range_ for _hyphen_ in the title? The reason is that there's some "ambiguity" as some citations use a rule (may be interpreted as a hyphen) for repeated author lists in the bibliography.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of solutions for your question.  The easiest is probably `cite.sty`:

> The cite package modifies LATEX’s normal citation mechanism for
>   improved handling of numeric citations. It provides compressed, sorted
>   lists of numerical or partly-numerical citations, as regular text or
>   as superscripts.  Generally, no changes to the usage of `\cite` commands
>   in the input are required.